# Launching AlertDialog From Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an AlertDialog, which is launched from a Fragment. It inflates a "reset password" layout in its View and looks like this:

[image]

I'm still trying to figure out the "correct" relationship between Fragments and Activities. My question is, is it ok to launch this type of AlertDialog from the Fragment itself or is it smarter to notify the Activity that a button was clicked in the Fragment and launch it from the Activity? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you should handle all of your UI relating to that fragment (like your button click) inside the fragment itself and only use the activity as a sort of container or controller to manage your fragments.

In this case, with something as simple as an AlertDialog, I would just pop it open from inside your fragment. However, if you were going to open another full fragment, then I would refer back to the activity via a callback method to open the new fragment.

Just with anything else, there are countless ways you could do it and it would be fine. I just think that way is a sort of "best practice".

Comment: deleted my Answer... this one is clearly better...Just pass getActivity() into the AlertDialog.Builder Constructor as shown here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog

Comment: @tbaxter. So is that a good general rule of thumb to follow/best practice? If you're using a FragmentManager and performing transactions between Fragments, alert the Activity and handle  it from there. Any UI stuff related to the Fragment handle it within the Fragment?

Comment: @MarkF Yes, it is. You want to keep your activity responsible only for maintaining the child fragments and managing their lifecycle. This way, it is easier to use the same code for both phones and tablets that may show different fragments on screen.